# Web scraping with beautiful soup 4 python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

So I just started using beautiful soup 4 and I came across a problem which I've been trying to solve for a few days but I can't.
Let me first paste the html code which I want to analyse:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover tenlaces tablesorter">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="al">Language</th>
<th class="ac">Link</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>


            <tr>
            <td class="tdidioma"><span class="flag flag_0">0</span></td>
            <td class="tdenlace"><a class="btn btn-mini enlace_link" data-servidor="42" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="Ver..." href="LINK I WANT TO SAVE0"><i class="icon-play"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Ver</a></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td class="tdidioma"><span class="flag flag_1">1</span></td>
            <td class="tdenlace"><a class="btn btn-mini enlace_link" data-servidor="42" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="Ver..." href="LINK I WANT TO SAVE1"><i class="icon-play"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Ver</a></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td class="tdidioma"><span class="flag flag_2">2</span></td>
            <td class="tdenlace"><a class="btn btn-mini enlace_link" data-servidor="42" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="Ver..." href="LINK I WANT TO SAVE2"><i class="icon-play"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Ver</a></td>
            </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see in each < tr > there are the < td > Language and Link. The problem is that I don't know how to relate the language to the link. I mean, I'd like to select for example if the space in language is 1 return the link. If not, don't do anything. But I'm only able to return the < td > with the language, not all the < tr > which is the important think
I don't know if I made my point because I don't really know how to explain

The code I have now gets the < tbody > from my main url but I don't really know how to make this I'm asking.

Thanks, and sorry for my bad English!

EDIT:
Here is a sample of my code so you can see what libraries I'm using and everything

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url = raw_input("Introduce URL to analyse: ")
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = Beautifulsoup(page.read())
body = soup.tbody
#HERE SHOULD BE WHAT I DON'T KNOW HOW TO DO
page.close()
```

Comment: what have you done so far? please give some code of yours.

Comment: I added a sample of my function in the end

Comment: Have a look at Scrapy (http://scrapy.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
result = None
for row in soup.tbody.find_all('tr'):
    lang, link = row.find_all('td')
    if lang.string == '1':
        result = link.a['href']
print result
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the soup like this, Probably you need some exception handling here

```
trs = soup.select('tr') # here trs is a list of bs4.element.Tag type element
```

Now iterate over the list,

```
for itm in trs:
    tds = itm.select('td')
    if tds:
        tdidoma, tdenlace = tds[0], tds[1] #assuming evey tr tag has atleast 2 td tags 
        print tdidoma.string
        print tdenlace.a['href']
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to check if the URL contains `1` and save it if it does. Is this what you want?

You can try playing with this code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(YOUR_TEXT_HERE)
tbody_soup = soup.find('tbody')
links = tbody_soup.find_all('a')
links_to_save = []

for item in links:
    print item.attrs['href'] # prints the url
    print item.get_text() # prints the text of the link
    print item.attrs # prints a dictionary with all the attributes

    # check if 1 is in url?
    if '1' in item.attrs['href']:
        links_to_save.append(item.attrs['href'])

print links_to_save
```